# How to read parent object value in LWC wire metho

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

How to read the Parent object field value in LWC, In the Below Soql fetching account.name, While reading in JS It's prints `undefined`

**Apex:**

```
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
  public static List<Contact> serviceCenterDetails(Id EnrollmentId) {          
    system.debug('ENROL ' + EnrollmentId);              
    return[SELECT AccountId, Account.name  FROM Contact WHERE User__c IN (SELECT  User__c  FROM 
   Enrollment__c WHERE Id = 'a082w000000ZR4x') limit 1];
}
```

**JS:**

```
@wire(serviceCenterDetails, { EnrollmentId: "$recordId" })
getservicecenter({ data, error }) {
if (data) {     
  let rtValues = Object.values(data); 
  for (let i = 0; i < rtValues.length; i++) {
    console.log("i -->" + i);
    console.log(
      "Id -->" + rtValues[i].AccountId
    );
    console.log(
      "Name -->" + rtValues[i].Account.name
    );

  }
}else {
  console.log("Svc Error  ===> " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
}
```

`Console.Log`
Id --> 0012w000003cDFDAW
Name -->undefined

Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex is case-insensitive, but JS is not. JS is case-sensitive.

Instead of

`console.log("Name -->" + rtValues[i].Account.name);`

you should use `Name` upper-case first letter

`console.log("Name -->" + rtValues[i].Account.Name);`

Comment: My bad:( Thanks @Oleksandr Berehovskyi